# Create Styleshhet and insertRule/addRule

Tags: javascript, css, grid, styles, stylesheet

im trying t create a stylesheet with JS and append some rules but it wont work.

```
if (style == null) {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
  style.setAttribute('data-style', 13);
  if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = '';
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
  }
  document.head.appendChild(style);

}
if (typeof style.insertRule === 'function') {
  style.insertRule("main > section[data-y='0']{top: 200px;}");
} else if (typeof style.addRule === 'function') {
  style.addRule("main > section[data-y='0']", "{top: 200px;}");
}
```

Sorry im new in Js.

Can someone tell me why this wont working?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar task, my example:

```
 $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test.css">');
    var sheets = document.styleSheets;
    console.log(sheets) //need to know number of my file, in my case e.g. it was 2
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[2];
    //also you forgot add index in the end of next line
    sheet.insertRule("body { background-color: #000;  }", 1);
```

its not a best example but it's work for me
and I found rly nice article about this task
https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!

addRule / insertRule isnt a function of style! Its a function of style.sheet and i forgot to set the index so it should be

```
if (typeof style.sheet.insertRule === 'function') {
  style.sheet.insertRule("main > section[data-y='0']{top: 200px;}",0);
} else if (typeof style.sheet.addRule === 'function') {
  style.sheet.addRule("main > section[data-y='0']", "{top: 200px;}",0);
}
```